# Browser Navigation Warning not Present on Documentation

Tags: feature-request, status-declined, documentation

I was making some improvements to a documentation page and went to attach an image.  I dragged it into the "drag here" window popup and missed ever so slightly, causing my browser to navigate to that file rather than uploading it via the drag-and-drop interface.

Hitting back on my browser returned me to the documentation area...minus all the editing I had done.

Why is there no navigate-away prevention on these pages? ("You are about to navigate away and may lose unsaved work, are you sure you wish to continue?")

Comment: Ouch. That's annoying. There was a drafts feature, so this might have been more of a bug than anything.

Comment: @JonEricson Thanks for the reply even if it is moot now. :)